# Why do the divs float like this?

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://www.timmerenonderhouddino.nl/producten-diensten/meubels-op-maat/kasten-op-maat/) of my website, the divs are floating in a strange way. The original theme (http://demo.fabthemes.com/revera/portfolio/) displays them in a correct way. I've checked the code + css but cannot seem to find the problem.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: Your missing the .row wrapper, see my answer below.

Comment: set an height to <article> or just write a line of text inside each article http://prntscr.com/5fnrf4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the  <kbd>min-height</kbd>:

```
article.post, article.page, section.error-404 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  min-height: 240px;
}
```

Comment: yup, they're floating like that because some of them have one, two or three lines of text. That changes the height of the boxes, causing the weird floating. Setting a min-height to accommodate three lines of text will do the trick.

Comment: yeah seriously, what's wrong with min-height?

Comment: Why downvote my answer, again? it is perfectly standard compliant solution. Dividing in row affects the markup, that is an extra effort...

Comment: someone just downvote spammed the whole thread... not cool.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the height. They need to be wraped in .row div. Twitter bootstrap is not rocket science. Should not have to worry about article hight.

Comment: Thanks a lot Giacomo Paita, that solved it!

Comment: You're welcome! If you are ok with my answer, could you please mark it as the accepted one? :)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your label stretches onto two lines makes it unhappy.

Consider making the `h3` a fixed height, or adding elements with `clear:both;` after every fourth item.

Comment: Site is responsive, you cannot clear 4th just like that.

Comment: @skobaljic Then use the "fixed height `h3`" option. That's rather the point of giving more than one option: not every option will be applicable.

Comment: Yes, fixed height of h3 is one of the options (if all images have same height), that's what I also suggested as 2nd option.

Comment: "Site is responsive, you cannot clear 4th just like that. " @skobaljic - yes, you could by JS.

Comment: You can clear with css, no problems, but what to do on 2 columns layout? Please read carefully.

Comment: @skobaljic Use media queries to change which `nth-child` you apply the clear to, obviously.

Comment: It is not obvious to Lars and other people, you should include example code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The height is not always the same. Do this:

```
article.post, article.page, section.error-404 {
```

margin-bottom: 40px;

min-height: 300px; <----

}

Answer (score 0):

Because some of the titles are in two lines, therefor, the height of blocks is not same. You can set this css to force them stay in one row:

```
.portbox h3 {
    height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You can also set the fixed height for `h3` that can hold 2 rows (or maximum you may have).

Answer (score -1):

You need nest every 4 columns in a div.row

```
  <div class="row">
    <article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">... </article>
    <article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">... </article>
    <article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">... </article>
    <article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">... </article>
</div> 
  <div class="row">
    <article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">... </article>
    <article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">... </article>
    <article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">... </article>
    <article class="col-sm-3 col-6 portbox post">... </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Site is responsive, this does nothing on 2 columns layout.

Comment: I assure you this is the issue. Should try the solution before downvoting.